# Как работает Actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, графика

Ситуация следующая:

```
public class PushingListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Начать бой")){
        Graphics.setButton("Продолжить бой", false);
        startBattle();
    }
}
```

Функция `startBattle()` срабатывает два раза.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            startBattle();
        }
    });
```

Функция `startBattle()` срабатывает один раз.

```
public static void setButton(String text, Boolean setActive) {
    button.setText(text);
    button.setEnabled(setActive);
    button.repaint();
}
```

Почему так происходит? Break напрямую не поставить

Comment: Продолжайте наблюдение... А если серьезно, в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как в ActionListener заставить исполняться функцию один раз

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать функцию `*кнопка*.setEnabled(false)`. По идее, оно отключает кнопку, и в итоге на неё нельзя больше нажимать. Но оно не всегда работает, поэтому 100% работы я не гарантирую.

Если вам нужно включить кнопку обратно, то пишете то же самое, только в параметрах пишете `true`.